# Number of edges in permutation graph

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

I'm trying to figure out how many edges there are in a graph where each vertex is a permutation of the integers $1,2,...,n$, and edges are drawn between the permutations that can be transformed into each other with one single transposition. And with transposition I mean swap places on any two elements in the permutation. So there are $n!$ vertices in the graph and each vertex has $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, but I'm not sure about how many edges there are in total. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems you are almost there, if each vertex has ${n}\choose{2}$ edges and we don't want to count doubles when you sum up all the edges you count each twice once from the "receiving" side and once from the "giving" side (I know this isn't a directed graph it just makes it easier to imagine). So the total number of edges would be $$n!\cdot{{n}\choose{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$